fctnl module while using py2app
i have python script - im in Windows im trying to convert it to .app so my supervisor can use it in his mac laptop.
but it showing error
import fcntl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
did anybody countered this, or knows what should i do to move forward?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html states that this is only available on Unix systems. This includes Mac OS and Linux but not MS Windows.
